# jQuery-UI: resizable - how to increase size of draggable edge?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery-UI's resizable edges to increase the height of a table.  I am wondering how to create a thicker bottom border which can be dragged? Increasing the border around the table doesn't make a difference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery UI Resizable - How to thicken handle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451285/jquery-ui-resizable-how-to-thicken-handle)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With calling `$(...).resize()`, you're able to set any child-element as handle.
[Take a look at this example](http://jsfiddle.net/89v9U/3/):

```
$( "#resizeDiv" ).resizable({handles: {'s': '#handle'}});
```

It enables resizing for the `#resizeDiv` at the bottom edge, assigning the `#handle` element as the active dragging area.

Answer (score 20):

You can achieve that by changing a bit of CSS:

**CSS** <sup>classes present on the Jquery UI style sheet</sup>

```
/* handle on the bottom */
.ui-resizable-s {
    height: 15px;
}

/* handle on the right */
.ui-resizable-e {
    width: 15px;
}
/* handle icon (corner) */
.ui-resizable-se {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
}
```

On this [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/YQXGp/) you can see it in action!

**Note:**

You don't really need to change anything on the jQuery UI Style Sheet, just declare the news css values after the inclusion of the jQuery UI Style Sheet!

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/89v9U/1/

You will need a new image for the resize handler, but heres something you can work with, its just CSS!